# How to call 2 Scrapy spiders in one python script?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using the the Scrapy CrawlSpider class to crawl category pages of e-Commerce websites. The issue is, that about 5% of the requests get rejected on 5 retries and it will not reach 100% of known categories.

My fix involves a second spider (scrapy.Spider) which gets the known URLs from the database that are missing and simply recrawles them. That way I achive 100%.

The problem is, that those are 2 different spiders which are in 2 different python files and need to be triggered by a cron job separately. In addition I simply copied the parse_item function to the other scraper which would require to do changes now on both scrapers if any are needed.

```
class myspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'categories'
    ...
    def parse_item(self, response):
        ...
        yield item


class myspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'recrawler'
    ...
    def parse_item(self, response):
        ...
        yield item
```

How can I extend the CrawlSpider class to recrawl after each finished cycle instead or call the other spider somehow?

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is, that about 5% of the requests get rejected on 5 retries and it will not reach 100% of known categories.

Increase the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` and lower `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`. Or use some proxies and rotate it on each request.

Don't solve a problem by introducing another problem.

BTW, `scrapy` does support starting multiple spiders and runs them in parallel. Check the doc [Running multiple spiders in the same process](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process).

Comment: Download delay is at 30s and I am using Proxies. Still 5%

Comment: Are these retried pages broken, or just because they recognized the spider and banned you? @merlin

Comment: No the definitely are working as the recrawl works. I get a denied response. Increasing above 30s is not an option as I need to finish the cycle before the day ends.